# How to lock a file in Actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, locking, flash-cs5

Using ActionScript 3.0, how can I lock a file? I'd like to write my highscores to a file and place the game on a server, but I don't want things to go wrong when two players submit their highscore at the same time. Does the `openAsync()` method of `FileStream` suffice for this?

Comment: You will need to manage server side database.

Comment: Rajneesh is correct, you cannot simply have a swf on a server and therefore have access to files on the server.  The swf is sent to the client machine and processed there, so each user of your flash app/game would have their own high scores list on their own machine.  In order to handle scores being submitted you'll need something like PHP, believe MySQL will handle the concurrency issues for you.  Other server side languages and databases would work equally well, but those are two I know and are well documented and free.

Comment: Ok, that sounds fair enough (and would also explain why nothing could be found on this matter). It's handy to know how the SWF gets processed. Thank you for your information, if you write it in an answer I'll gladly accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to shaunhusain:

> When placing your project on a webserver, the SWF-file is sent to the client machine and processed there, so each
>   user of your flash app/game would have their own high scores list on
>   their own machine. In order to handle scores being submitted you'll
>   need something like PHP, believe MySQL will handle the concurrency
>   issues for you. Other server side languages and databases would work
>   equally well, but those are two I know and are well documented and
>   free.